# How can I make any number of divs stand side-by-side horizontally and dividing equally the whole page width?

Tags: html, css

How can I make any number of divs stand side-by-side horizontally in a wrapper div and make sure that they fill the whole page width **without fixing wrapped divs width** (exactly like html table columns behave when setting table width to 100%)?

And cross-browser as most as possible...

Thanks

Comment: this could be done in javascript or jquery

Comment: I have tried making each wrapped divs float:left but this force me to set manually the % width of each div to: 100/(nb of divs)...

Comment: Does this can only be achieved by calculating and setting each divs width dynamically with Javascript? Why does this work with html table but can't be reproduced with divs?

Comment: Because that's how HTML tables are designed to work. Divs are meant to be a horizontal division of the page, the fact that they can float is an extension to their original design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit of a cheat but you can do it using display:table-cell like this;

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #wrap {
        background:black;
        display:table;
        padding:10px 0;
        width:100%;
    }
    .box {
        height:100px;
        display:table-cell;
    }

    .a {
        background:red;
    }

    .b {
        background:blue;
    }

    .c {
        background:green;
    }

    .d {
        background:yellow;
    }
 </style>
```

and HTML like so;

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="box a">a</div>
    <div class="box b">b</div>
    <div class="box c">c</div>
    <div class="box d">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work as the sizes won't be equal if the content of each is different. I think you'd have to use javascript to count the number of divs and assign percentage widths.

Comment: it's not a big problem if they are not exactly of same size... This may be a solution but I can't make it work in ie9... Everything nice with ff but with ie9 all divs are vertically aligned.

Comment: I don't have a working VM with IE9 at the moment so can't test but the display:table-cell and display:table-row properties are both supported by IE9. As a test try adding ANOTHER wrapping div with a display property of table.... seems a bit odd to do this though.

Comment: Just took a screenshot with Browserlab which indicates my code works in IE9. http://d.pr/i/YLfm

Comment: You are right, it work now with ie9... The <!doctype ..> markup was missing in my page and this was making ie9 to fail.

Comment: You may also find you don't actually need that #wrap div either.

Comment: Furthermore, the result appears to be the same as when using the CSS3 flexbox property but with, I think, better current browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. It uses jquery, which makes it about as cross browser as posible:

http://jsfiddle.net/AmnsD/

Aww, SO doesn't allow just linking to jsfiddle: so here's the example:

```
<style>
.inner1{background-color:#FF0000;float:left;height:25px;}
.inner2{background-color:#00FF00;float:left;height:25px;}
.inner3{background-color:#0000FF;float:left;height:25px;}
.inner4{background-color:#FFFF00;float:left;height:25px;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#outer').children().each(function(index){
        $(this).css('width',100/$('#outer').children().length + '%');
    });
});​
</script>

<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner1">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="inner3">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="inner4">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be what u are looking for: http://umaar.github.com/css-flexbox-demo/

edit:
THis is hover now very cross-browser (does not work in ie9-)

Comment: This look very promising... But is it disponible right now in major browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved using responsive web design, with media queries.

Comment: Media queries will let you specify different CSS rules based on screen resolution and orientation. This does not address the fundamental core of this question in that the OP wants an unspecified number of elements to span, and fill the page width.